# tiny white worms, and black spots/dots on leaves of my basil and chilis

Tags: leaves, worms

Recently I have found on my chili plants a weird thing that happened a long time ago on a basil plant I bought from the shops.

[image]

If I had to describe it, they are tiny white/translucent worms with a black dot, that are often left on the leaves. You can zoom on it to see two individuals.
Most of my plants are respected but basil and chilis.

I also have fungus gnats, coming from my soil, would you think it can be the larvae? I read they are not causing anything to the plant and rarely to the roots.. well ?

1. what is it?
2. an idea to treat them? (Organically if possible). Please note I have soil blocks, which then render complicated some treatments

Answer (score 0):

those white worms can be white flies. and those symptoms can be of Begomoviruses, try removing weed plants from your vicinity.